# Creating an object from unknown type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have three classes. A B and C. A and B both derived from C (C has OAuth properties), and A and B both have different properties other than C properties

I have a function that sets the OAuth properties of both A and B, but because they are different types I pass in an object through the method. I then check to see if A is A and B is B, but I don't know where to set the OAuth properties (i don't want to duplicate my code)

```
public string SerializeForAPI(object myObject)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    if (myObject is A)
    {
        A data = (A)myObject; 
    }
    else if (myObject is B) 
    {
        B data = (B)myObject;
    }
    // these are obviously not set because the object is within the if statement
    data.oauth_consumer_key = this.ConsumerKey;
    data.oauth_token = this.Token;

    string serialized = jsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Create a function that takes a `C`, and pass your `A` object or `B` object?

Comment: I could do that, but within that function that I pass the A object or the B object, I will still have to convert them to a certain type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method should accept an object of type `C`, not an object of type `object`.

```
public string SerializeForAPI(C myObject)
```

Now you can pass in either an `A` or a `B` instance to this method, and the method can be sure that anything passed into it will have the `oauth_consumer_key` and `oauth_token` members, so this method can do everything that it needs with this type.  By not having a parameter of type `object` it's not even *possible* to pass in an object that won't work.

Comment: but if I am setting the properties of A and B before calling SerializeForAPI, how do I keep those properties?

Comment: @user3192012 They never go away.  That this method is treating the object as its base class doesn't mean it doesn't also have all of the fields from the more derived class.

Comment: Ah you are correct! as B is a part of C, sending B as a C still keeps the B properties. that is the trouble I had, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just cast it to a `C`, if you know that the `myObject` will always be a subclass of it:

```
C data = (C) myObject;
data.oauth_consumer_key = this.ConsumerKey;
// etc.
```

Comment: BTW, you do not need to explicitly cast to a base type. `(C)` is not necessary.

Comment: @Dmitry Sure it is, because `myObject` has type `object` ... look at the OP code again.

Comment: ah, sorry... my bad 8)

Comment: but will the casted object with all the properties of class A carry over? For example: if A has a property called FirstName, but C does not, how will the objects be carried over?

Comment: @user3192012 Not sure what you mean. You won't be able to access the `A`-specific properties of the object via `data` (you'd have to check it with `is` in a conditional and set them there, as in your original post).

Comment: @user3192012 to elaborate... with a reference of type `C` you can access only the members declared by class `C`. With a reference of type `A` you can access the members declared by `A` and the members inherited from `C`.

Comment: ah yes, I want to serialize the whole object regardless if it's A or B